# Broken perl packages

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, git

I am trying to install git on ubuntu, however, it returns

```
root@localhost:~# apt install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 git : Depends: perl but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: liberror-perl but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I understand that many times, git is installed by default. But not this time. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What Ubuntu version ?

Comment: You have held broken packages (ie. likely problems from prior commands that weren't fixed, that need to be fixed first).  You can `sudo apt -f install` to try and -fix-broken though you didn't provide you release so adjust to your version.  Your perl error implies you're not using Ubuntu, or you have a problem with your sources (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=perl&searchon=names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is not installed by default, but is being available to install after you make a packages info update:

```
sudo apt update
```

Also, make sure, you have supported Ubuntu version by `cat /etc/lsb-release`. Supported Ubuntu versions now are 16.04 LTS, 18.04 LTS, 19.10, ESM paid support versions from 12.04 till 18.04.

For Ubuntu 19.10 you could have the next `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://en.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan main restricted
deb http://en.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates main restricted
deb http://en.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan universe
deb http://en.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates universe
deb http://en.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan multiverse
deb http://en.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-updates multiverse
#deb http://en.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ eoan-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security multiverse
```

But if you have some testing or unstable repositories enabled and install some packages from them, they could point to not existing packages. You could also move your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` config files to other backup folder.

Then you could try to remove dependent packages if they are present, then `sudo apt clean`, `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install git` again.

You could also use `sudo apt install -f` to correct issues when you've installed some packages usually manually using `dpkg -i <package-name>.deb` command.

Comment: Worked really well, now, it is possible to install git.